# Finding matches in nested blocks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

I have an array of `dates` and an object `tests`, which is submitted by the user:

```
dates = []
today = Date.today + 1
(today - 31..today).each{|date| dates.push(date.to_s)}
tests = company.tests.where(date: today - 31..today).order(date: :asc)
```

I'm iterating over each `date`, and if there is a `test` that matches the `date`, I add it to a `score` array. There may be multiple, hence the `average` calculation.

```
score = []
array = []
dates.each do |r|
  tests.each do |t|
    if t.date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") == r
      score.push(t.security_percentage)
    end
  end
  average = score.reduce(:+).to_i / score.size
  array.push(average)
end
```

I'm stuck trying to figure out how to insert a `0` if there aren't any tests for the given date. I expect `array` to have 31 entries:

```
[0, 98, 89, 99, 0, 0, ...]
```

but it only has 20 entries since I only have 20 tests.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm stuck trying to figure out how to insert a 0 if there aren't any
>   tests for the given date.

You can push as much zeros as you need to after your code is done:

```
(1..31-array.size).each do |x|
  array.push(0)
end
```

Thats not pretty but answers the question I guess

---

> I need to only push them if there is no test for the given date that's
>   currently being iterated through.

How about this one:

```
if t.date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") == r
  score.push(t.security_percentage)
else
  score.push(0)
end
```

Comment: That's actually quite similar to what I originally had.  The problem is that I can't just fill up the remaining space with zeros.  I need to only push them if there is no test for the given date that's currently being iterated through.

Comment: So, push a `0` 30+ times to the `score` array since the other test dates won't match?

Answer (score 0):

Ended up learning about using `.select`:

```
dates = []
array = []
today = Date.today + 1
tests = company.tests.where(date: today - 31..today).order(date: :asc)
(today - 31..today).each{|date| dates.push(date.to_s)}
  dates.each do |r|
    score = []
    matches = tests.select{ |t| t.date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") == r }
    if matches.length > 0
      matches.each do |m|
        score.push(m.security_percentage)
      end
      average = score.reduce(:+).to_i / score.size
      array.push(average)
    else
      array.push(0)
    end
  end
```